# How to avoid Werewolves

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I'm playing D&D 3.5 and we are about to travel through lands where Werewolves are living. There aren't many of them but we need to deceive them somehow, so that, if it comes to a fight, we don't lure more of them by (for example) our scent.

Is there a some way to mask our scent so werewolves **won't** smell us so we can sneak and kill/bypass them? or any other kind of tricks that would be helpful against them?

I'm a Ranger, and it depends who will go, we will probably have a Cleric or even two, a warrior, assassin, Hexblade and maybe a wizard. The party levels are 8–16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Slipping Past Werewolves

This is the big deal.

- The 1st-level Drd and Rgr spell [***pass without trace***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/passWithoutTrace.htm) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 259) for 1 hour/level grants 1 touched creature/level the ability to leave neither tracks nor scent, making tracking the creature impossible except with magic.

Although these might also be of interest.

- The 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell ***dead end*** [illus] (*Spell Compendium* 59) for 10 min./level grants 1 touched creature/level immunity from being tracked by the Search skill, the Survival skill, and the extraordinary ability scent. Creatures interacting with the illusion get Willpower saving throws.
- The 0th-level spell ***no light*** [evoc] (*Book of Vile Darkness* 100) for 1 min./level creates a 20-ft. radius spread of essentially magical mundane darkness that, among other things, *should* impede creatures' low-light vision. *Note:* The spell wasn't updated from a 3.0 source; the DM must adjust the spell for his campaign accordingly.